# Pathway for drone racing

Tags: civil-engineering, rf-electronics, consumer-electronics

How can I build a v shaped pathway for drones? It would be a sort of racing path and there would be multiple drones flying over the pathway at the same time.

The race would be a relay race. So there are multiple path breakpoints and each drone would have to carry a small item passed onto it while racing over the path. We have to protect the item at all cost and also be really fast at the same time in order to win the race.

The shape of the path is "V" because I would like to build a v shaped inflatable structure which would protect the drones if they fall off onto the path while racing.

1 more point: since a drone racing envrionment would take quite a lot of space, all of this would be built in a small hilly area where it would be quite windy.

So what material can I use to make the drone racing pathway? What material to use for the inflatable v shape pathway? What to use so that it resists wind?

Any other mechanism can be suggested for the pathway keeping in mind 2 important factors

1. Protection of the item
2. Speed

Thanks

Comment: Why inflatable? Doesn’t sound very wind resistant...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too specialized a topic and unlikely to be of general interest

Comment: @JonathanRSwift any other pathway would do fine. An inflatable v shaped path was my 1st impression to catch the item and drone if they fall off. Any other suggestions/mechanisms would do too.

Answer (score 1):

you can use plastic light gauge garden netting. They come in typical sizes of 50ft by 50ft at approximately under 10cents/sqft.
They can be secured by thin cords to stakes or anchors.